# Replace String in a JSON file

Tags: python, json, bash, shell, awk

```
"cassandra": {
    "host": "1.1.1.1",
    "portNo": "9042",
    "keyspace": "good"
},
"postgres": {
    "host": "2.2.2.2",
    "portNo": "5432",
    "database": "dude",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "something"
}
```

This is a part of the json file. I need to edit the hosts part with two different IPs using a script. Anyone have any idea

Comment: Yes. 1. Load the file into a Python object. 2. Loop over the object, replacing the  `"host"` value of each dictionary, as desired. 3. Convert back to JSON and save. What part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: post the replacement items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For proper json (your data above surrounded by `{}`) using `jq`:

```
$ jq '.|.cassandra.host="foo"' file.json
{
  "cassandra": {
    "host": "foo",
    "portNo": "9042",
    "keyspace": "good"
  },
  "postgres": {
    "host": "2.2.2.2",
    "portNo": "5432",
    "database": "dude",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "something"
  }
}
```

Comment: If I need the changes to be in the file. What should I do ?

Comment: Redirect it to a new file with `jq ... file.json > new.json`. There is no inplace option for `jq`.

Comment: one more question, if I point the value from a variable , is it work. Means jq '.|.cassandra.host="$ip"' file.json . where $p=1.1.1.1

Comment: If you quote it right, I'd assume: `ip=asdasd; jq ".|.cassandra.host=\"$ip\"" file.json`

Comment: right ....the following also worked.................. ip="1.1.1.1" && jq --arg ip $ip '.|.cassandra.host=$ip' file.json

Answer (score 1):

You can use Json python package

```
import json

my_bytes_value = response.content
my_json = my_bytes_value.decode('utf8')
jsonResponse = json.loads(my_json)
resultCount = jsonResponse["cassandra"]
```